# How to filter multiple columns data to one column in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have two columns data contain "#N/A" and "Data", but I have not any idea to filter/combine to one column.

So see below pic,
How to combine(or filter) multiple columns to D column?

Can give me a hint to solve?

[image: Except result]

Comment: `=IfError(A2, B2)`

Comment: @TimWilliams, 
Thanks. Let me ask another situation
If I have more columns to filter one, 
Has it suggestion method?

Comment: Provide a data sample that represents your REAL situation. Don't start a question with a data sample that is not what you really need and then tack on more and more to the question. Edit your question. Show us all your possible scenarios. Anything else is wasting our time.

Comment: @teylyn Sorry, my bad
I edit my question and title. I think this my final scenarios.

Comment: Is there any possibility of having less than 2 #N/As in a whole row? (i.e. multiple `Filiing ...`)

Comment: Why is the result in row 2 #N/A? there is a value in column B. Why is the result in the 11th row NOT #N/A? There are no other values in that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there is only one "wanted" value in a row and assuming that a row can contain all unwanted #N/A values, you can use this array formula, which must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter, starting in row 1, then copied down

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/NOT(ISNA(A1:C1)),A1:C1)
```

[image]